# Each function in jquery not looping

Tags: javascript, jquery, django

I have a table with the below values using django.

```
<tr>
    <td>Chips</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>20.00</td>
    <td id='totalperitem'>40.00</td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td>pizza</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>100.00</td>
    <td id='totalperitem'>200.00</td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td>Peanut Butter</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>50.00</td>
    <td id='totalperitem'>100.00</td>
</tr>
```

I'm trying to get the total of the totalperitem column using the jquery 'each' function. However , i'm only getting the value of the first item.

jquery syntax:

```
$('#totalperitem').each(function () {
    running_total += parseInt($(this).text());
    console.log('sum : ' + running_total);
});
```

this is the output im getting in the console

```
sum : 40
```

What am i doing wrong?

Thanks,
KJ

Comment: `id` attribute **must** be unique. It's an *identifier*, and as such is used to identify separate elements.

Comment: Id should be unique! give them a class

Answer (score 2):

Multiple elements with same ID are not allowed in one page.

Use `class` instead of `id`

```
<td class='totalperitem'>200.00</td>
```

And use `.totalperitem` as selector.

```
var running_total = 0;
$('.totalperitem').each(function(){
    running_total += parseInt($(this).text());
    console.log('sum : ' + running_total);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `class` instead of `id` and do,

```
var sum = $('.totalperitem').get().reduce(function(a,b){
  return a + parseFloat(b.innerHTML);
},0);
```